# How in implement Triggers in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, substring, cursors

Using Oracle 11g, I am trying to get the last character of a the name of a course via a trigger and then depending on the last character, It assigns a grade to the student.

I have tried several different approaches to the problem, I get several different errors, its giving me a headache. I am not sure if I am approaching the cursor wrong or the whole problem.

```
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME, GRADE) VALUES (234501,153, '078',256877 , 'Intro to Holographic',"") ;
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME, GRADE) VALUES (234519,153, '078',256877 ,'Intro to Holographic' ,"") ;
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME ,GRADE) VALUES (234505,153, '078',256877 ,'Intro to Holographic', "") ;
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME, GRADE) VALUES (23405,21, '012A',23532 ,'Starfleet Intro', "") ;
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME, GRADE) VALUES (23419,21, '012A',23532 ,'Starfleet Intro', "") ;
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME, GRADE) VALUES (23401,21, '012A',23532 ,'Starfleet Intro', "") ;
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME, GRADE) VALUES (23418,21, '012A',23532 ,'Starfleet Intro', "") ;
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME, GRADE) VALUES (234520,933,'278',843234 ,'Borg Technolgy', "");
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME, GRADE) VALUES (234505,933,'278',843234 ,'Borg Technolgy' ,"");
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID,COURSENAME, GRADE) VALUES (234501,933,'278',843234 ,'Borg Technolgy' ,""); 
INSERT INTO GRADES (STUDNETID, SECTIONID, SECTIONINFO, COURSEID, COURSENAME,GRADE) VALUES (234519,438,'531',542303 , 'Intro to Genetics',""); 

create or replace TRIGGER gradeTrigger
AFTER Update ON Grade For Each Row
  declare 

 cursor courseTitle_cur IS 
  select g.COURSENAME
  from Grade g;

lastChar String (1);
gradeLetter String(1); 
   BEGIN

   for courseTitle_cur in CourseName
                 loop
        SubStr(CourseName, -1):= lastChar;
      end loop;
   If(lastChar = 'A' OR lastChar ='B'OR lastChar = 'C' OR lastChar = 'D' OR lastChar = 'E'OR lastChar = 'F') THEN
 gradeLetter := "A";

ELSIF(lastChar = 'G'OR lastChar = 'H'OR lastChar = 'I'OR lastChar = 'J'OR lastChar = 'K')THEN
 gradeLetter := "B";

ELSIF (LASTCHAR = 'L'or LASTCHAR = 'M'or LASTCHAR = 'N'or LASTCHAR = 'O'or LASTCHAR = 'P')then
 gradeLetter := "C";

ELSIf (LASTCHAR = 'Q' OR LASTCHAR = 'R'OR LASTCHAR = 'S'OR LASTCHAR = 'T')THEN
 gradeLetter := "D";

ELSIf (lastChar = 'U' OR lastChar ='V'OR lastChar = 'W'OR lastChar = 'X'OR lastChar = 'Y' OR lastChar = 'Z')THEN
 gradeLetter := "E";

Return gradeLetter;
end if ; 
   End;
```

I get errors like 'Error(16,2): PL/SQL: Statement ignored' or 'Error(4,10): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "G"."COURSENAME": invalid identifier' This is very frustrating because I cannot pinpoint why its being ignored or is invalid.

Comment: We don't know what your tables look like. Please edit your question and include the structure of your GRADE and COURSENAME tables, including all field names and data types. Thanks. In the meantime: there is no String data type in PL/SQL. Use VARCHAR2(x). String constants in PL/SQL should be enclosed in single-quotes, not double-quotes. You cannot assign a value to a function, such as SUBSTR. And triggers don't have a return value.

Comment: @BobJarvis I edited the post with what I am inserting into the table. Thanks for the advice on the string constraints on PL/SQL

Comment: According to your edit, the name of table is `GRADES`, not GRADE. Also, the name of the field is `GRADE`, not GRADELETTER. You might try making those substitutions and see if things work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how triggers work in Oracle.

Each row that is updated has a before and after state - these are represented by the `:old` and `:new` records respectively.

If you want to specify what the value of a field should look like after the update is applied, you need to change the field in the `:new` record **before** the update is applied.

Therefore, I think your trigger should probably look something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER grade_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON grades
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF substr(upper(:new.coursename), -1) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
  THEN
    :new.grade := 'A';
  ELSIF substr(upper(:new.coursename), -1) IN ('G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K')
  THEN
    :new.grade := 'B';
  ELSIF substr(upper(:new.coursename), -1) IN ('L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P')
  THEN
    :new.grade := 'C';
  ELSIF substr(upper(:new.coursename), -1) IN ('Q', 'R', 'S', 'T')
  THEN
    :new.grade := 'D';
  ELSIF substr(upper(:new.coursename), -1) IN ('U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')
  THEN
    :new.grade := 'E';
  END IF;
END grade_trigger;
/
```

and here's [proof that it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cc361bde7f00407fed6a86c2c474d371).

Comment: Oracle is giving me an error that there is bad binding, also I feel like I should be using a cursor for this @Boneist

Comment: @Boneist: looking at OP's recent edit to the question, it appears that the name of table is `GRADES`, not GRADE. Also, the name of the field is `GRADE`, not GRADELETTER. Darn these nitpicky stupid computers..! :-)

Comment: @Starfire I've updated my answer, and given you a demo of a working trigger. Why do you think you need a cursor? That seems like a bad thing to do - why would you want to update the entire table every time you update each row?

Comment: @Boneist I was thinking I would have needed a cursor to loop through the records. Now that I see it running I can see the FOR EACH ROW function covers that